# Was Wednesday admitted to Nevermore as a 'normie'?

Tags: wednesday

In [*Wednesday*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wednesday_(TV_series)), as far as I can tell, the students of Nevermore Academy all appear to have at least some supernatural ability (vampires, sirens, telekinetics, psychics, etc). People without supernatural ability are considered 'normies'. Even the staff appears to be supernatural, as they make an explicit mention of Ms. Thornhill being the school's first 'normie' teacher.

We know of course that Wednesday herself is psychic and experiences visions.

However, Wednesday keeps this entirely to herself, at least up until the pilot episode.

Principal Weems confronts her about her psychic ability, and she admits to it. But this is *after* she's already been admitted to the school.

So at the time of her admission, would Wednesday have been admitted as a 'normie', at least from the school's point of view, and why was this acceptable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most important thing to note here is that people are not admitted to Nevermore on the basis of having supernatural abilities. Principal Weems notes, in a rather offended tone, when confronted about Tyler's mother having been a Hyde, that she "never asked her how she identified." Obviously, if Principal Weems is not asking people whether they have any supernatural traits, she cannot be doing much more than admitting people who apply regardless of whether they have those talents or not. Indeed, the school's terminology reinforces this: the school is for "outcasts," which is clearly *largely* taken to be a euphemism for supernatural creatures, but need not be. If Wednesday says that she belongs at the school, Weems will not question her.

The thing is that very few people without supernatural powers would *want* to attend or teach at a school where they could be petrified or mind-controlled *purely by accident*, and that is before taking into account the rampant prejudice against the outcast community. There does not seem to be an official policy against "normie" teachers or students; they just do not want to go there.

It is also worth noting that many (all?) supernatural characteristics seem to be heritable on the show, and Morticia and Gomez seem to have attended Nevermore. So if they were good enough for Weems's predecessor at that time, then presumably she would have had no objection to their daughter even if Nevermore only did admit people with supernatural traits.

Comment: Minor niggle: "if they were good enough for Weems at that time" Weems and Morticia were roommates. Weems wasn't the principal at the time.

Comment: Right - Good observations. In other words, even without direct evidence of supernatural ability, the Addams reputation wouldn't really qualify them as 'normies' anyway.